# Splitting string to integer from single-line user input?

Tags: ruby, user-input, split

I just started learning some ruby, and I want to do something like this:

```
print "Insert two numbers: "
a, b = gets.split(" ")
```

but I want to make a and b to be integers at the same time (in the same line).. If I add `.to_i` to the second line (before or after `split(" ")`), it doesn't work... so, how should I approach this? mapping, splitting, slicing? ok, I know I could use scanf, but other than scanf, how would I do this?

sorry for such a noobish question, but I just couldn't find a good enough answer only googling...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a, b = gets.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
```

Or more universal:

```
a, b = gets.scan(/\-?\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a , b = gets.split.map { |num| num.to_i }
```

This should work